# MediaRecorder video storage after confirmation

Tags: android, video, storage, mediarecorder

Capturing a video is part of an application I'm currently working on. Video capturing and storing works fine.

I followed the android [tutorial for video capturing](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) and all recorded videos are stored directly after the recording stops.

Is there any way to let the user decide (via dialog) if he/she wants to store the video?
I don't really want to delete the video afterwards.

Comment: Why don't you want to delete it afterwards?  Doing so yourself vs. doing it in an automatically cleaned up temp folder it likely just a semantic difference.  At best you would change which flash device was suffering the wear, but if the device has a removable card it would probably be better to put the wear on that rather than the internal storage which cannot be replaced - and realistically it's unlikely an issue unless you have some automated system continuously recording and deleting.

Comment: makes sense and i will do it like this then. thanks